# Does sleeping on one side affect cognitive development?

Tags: sleep, brain, position, development-disorder

I have been sleeping mainly on my right side for as long as I can remember. I am wondering whether this could have had any effect on my cognitive development?

I can image that gravity pulling down the blood to the right side may lead to a minor difference in pressure and available oxygen between the left and right side of my brain. Does this mean that different parts of my brain take a more substantial part in processing the events of the day?  Could this difference accumulate to something noticeable and permanent over the course of a lifetime?

Answer (score 1):

No, this will have no affect on your cognitive processes. It may affect your sleep pattern; side sleeping help open your airways  allowing you to breath better. Don't sleep on your back if you're snore. Don't sleep on a sore or bruise, this will put pressure on it, sometimes that may be good. Most of the time though this may make your recovery slower.

The fluid in your cranium called  Cerebrospinal actually keeps your brain balanced when you are sleep, so your brain is not taking extra pressure in any form.
Now if you were to get smacked, your brain will move of course. But as long as your still your brain is pretty much at an equal balance.

[Read more](https://restrite.com/sleep-positions-and-your-brain/)

Don't worry your body is and incredibly engineered structure. Your body is prepared for anything *natural*. Now if you sleep upside down that may cause some problems because that not position your body is *programmed* for.

Diseases of course can cause your body to reprogram itself.